# How to build multimodule Spring/Maven project as standalone executable jar?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

**Github example:** https://github.com/jnemecz/multimodule-sandbox

---

I went through several articles regarding multi module Maven/Spring projects, most of them deal with the structure but do not explain the principle of building a standalone executable `jar` of the given sub-project.

Until now I used to separate Spring/Maven projects into separated directories and with `spring-boot-maven-plugin` set up the executable of the given project. All projects has one separated build configuration.

Now I want to combine four separate projects into one and divide them using modules in this structure:

- {parent} <- `pom`
- data <- `jar`, executable
- commons <- `jar`, libraries, not executable
- backend <- `jar`, executable
- infrastructure <- `jar`, libraries, not executable

Now I'm not sure how the module build works in this multi module project. I imagine that I build the `backend` module using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, I will build it with `mvn clean package -P{profile}` and it will automatically build all dependencies (`commons` module and external Maven libraries) and create executable `jar` file as usual.

This is parent `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>example-backend</module>
        <module>example-data</module>
        <module>example-commons</module>
        <module>example-infrastructure</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <deriva.commons.version>1.79</deriva.commons.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.deriva.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>deriva-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${deriva.commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

and this is `pom.xml` from "module project" `backend`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>example-backend</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start.class>com.example.backend.ApplicationRoot</start.class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>example-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <mainClass>${start.class}</mainClass>
                    <layout>JAR</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run `mvn clean package -Pproduction` to build a production ready `jar` this error occures:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project example-backend: Could not
> resolve dependencies for project com.example:example-backend:jar:1.0:
> com.example:example-commons:jar:1.0 was not found in
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This
> failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not
> reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or
> updates are forced -> [Help 1]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have an example project or this one on github or alike?

Comment: @khmarbaise No, but I can create one if it's necessary.

Comment: Would be great so we can give concrete hint where to change/improve...

Comment: @khmarbaise https://github.com/jnemecz/multimodule-sandbox

Comment: Is that correct that you are mixing spring boot 2.7.X and spring boot 3?

Comment: @khmarbaise No, it's supposed to be 2.7, that would be a quick sample of the structure, I'll fix the library versions - fixed

Comment: Added PR to create a full working example....take a look...

Comment: @khmarbaise Perfect, now it works! Feel free to post an answer, it will be accepted.

Comment: You should update your post because you have deleted the github repository...

Answer (score 0):

The parent of the project should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>sandbox-backend</module>
        <module>sandbox-commons</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.12</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <deriva.commons.version>1.79</deriva.commons.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>cz.deriva.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>deriva-commons</artifactId>
                <version>${deriva.commons.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

So the first module (`sandbox-commons`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>sandbox-commons</artifactId>
</project>
```

and the last module (`sandbox-backend`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>sandbox-backend</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```